# Prove that a relation is ordering relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

$\beta\subset A^2$ is reflexive and transitive relation.$\alpha$ is an equivalence relation defined on A by $x\alpha y \iff x\beta y$ and $y\beta x$. A factor set (no idea what the english term is for this) $A/_\alpha$ is defined such that it contains all the classes of set A. Prove that the relation $\le$ defined by 
$x^\alpha \le y^\alpha \iff x\beta y$ is ordering on $A/_\alpha$.

Here is my solution so far. Obviously we need to prove that $\le$ is antisymmetric,reflexive and transitive.

Reflexive :

Since $\beta$ is reflexive if $x\in\beta$ then $x\beta x \implies x^\alpha\le x^\alpha$

Antisymmetry:

Here is where my problem occurs. We have no information whether $\beta$ is symmetric or not. Perhaps I don't even need it.

Transitivity:

Since $\beta$ is transitive then there exist $x,y,z\in A$ such that $x\beta y$ and $y\beta z \implies x\beta z$. By the definition of $\le$ from $x\beta y \implies x^\alpha \le y^\alpha $, $y\beta z \implies y^\alpha \le z^\alpha $ and , $x\beta z \implies x^\alpha \le z^\alpha$.

Are my proofs about reflexivity and transitivity enough. How would you approach proving antisymmetry?

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: Well basically we say that $x^\alpha$ = {$y\in A$ | $y\alpha x$}. The set containing all these classes ( also know as equivalence classes ) is the set $A/\alpha$

Comment: OK, you now defined $x^\alpha$, and you defined $A/\alpha$. But what is $\alpha$? What do we know about it? Is it an equivalence relation? Is it in any way connected to $\beta$?

Comment: It is more of a notation as far as I know and it is of no particular interest to the question. We basically use it to note the classes of this set.

Comment: It's in the question, so it's good to know what it is. Is it an equivalence relation?

Comment: Side note: This question had two parts but I split it because I already solved the first one. In this case $\alpha$ used to be another relation defined by $x\alpha y \iff x\beta y$ and $y\beta x$. 

You needed to prove that $\alpha$ is equivalence relation , perhaps I made a mistake thinking it is of no real interest to the second part beside it's definition.

Comment: **That's not a side note!!!** I thought $\alpha$ was just "any" relation, in which case the relation $\leq$ is not even well defined (see my answer below). You see?! This is why you need to give details in your question. I just spent 10 minutes writing up a nice proof of how the relation you define is ill defined, and it's all worthless because you only gave half the information in your question...

Comment: So is there a nice solution after I edited it? My apology for the mistake.

Comment: By the way, you must prove _antisymmetry_, not just asymmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to prove is not *asymmetry* (i.e., the fact that a relation is not symmetric) but *antisymmetry*.

You need to prove that if $x^\alpha\leq y^\alpha$ and $y^\alpha\leq x^\alpha$, then $x^\alpha=y^\alpha$.

To do that:

1. Assume that $x^\alpha\leq y^\alpha$ and $y^\alpha\leq x^\alpha$
2. Therefore, because $x^\alpha\leq y^\alpha$, we know that $x\beta y$.
3. Also, because $y^\alpha\leq x^\alpha$, we know that $y\beta x$.

Can you conclude, from (2) and (3), that $x^\alpha=y^\alpha$?

(Remember $x^\alpha=y^\alpha$ if and only if $x\alpha y$, so you need to prove that).

Answer (score 1):

To prove antisymmety, you must assume $X\le Y$ and $Y \le X$ and then find a way to conclude $X=Y$.

Let's set $X=x^\alpha$ and $Y=y^\alpha$. What we know is then that $x\mathrel{\beta}y$ and $y\mathrel{\beta} x$. But that means exactly that $x\mathrel{\alpha} y$.

Can you see that this implies that $x^\alpha=y^\alpha$?